# Is there some kind of encoding you need to do in order to populate the url in dynamodb?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

So I have been following an advanced dynamodb design pattern involving my range / sort keys to contain items / status appended to the string. An example is as follows:

### Sort key

NY#NYC#JFK11

The example above is essentially a location. The challenge I am coming across is the hashtag #. When I retrieve my data following that example I can see the sort key appear as I hover over a link on the front end however, everything after the first hash tag is blank in the url. So when I try to query specific details on the key above all that gets populated in the url when clicking on a table link is NY and everything after the hashtag is forgotten.

Does anybody know why or how to go around this? I remember reading that there can't be any hashtags in the url and you'd have to encode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the javascript functions `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent`. For your example:

```
encodeURIComponent("NY#NYC#JFK11") === "NY%23NYC%23JFK11"
```

and to decode:

```
decodeURIComponent("NY%23NYC%23JFK11") === "NY#NYC#JFK11"
```

So you'd have to write the encoded Sort Key in the URL, extract it from the URL and decode it. Your URL would change from `domain/NY#NYC#JFK11` to `domain/NY%23NYC%23JFK11`.